# Apply regular expressions to compare values in data frames of different length in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, variable-length

I am trying to apply a regular expression to match values in two data frames of different length in R. My objective is to retain only the values that match the regex in both data frames.

An example of the dataset would be:

```
a<-c('item1','item2','item4')
b<-c('item1','\t item2','item3','item4')
```

I tried to do `grepl(a$. , b$.)` but it only works for the 'first' row. Just to explain, the values in the two columns have a common kernel name but there might be small differences, so I do need some kind of regex.

If the code worked, I would get that the new object 'c', which could also be a filtered version of a, would be equal to

```
c<-c('item1','item2','item4')
```

Peace to you

Comment: Try with `grep(paste(a, collapse = "|"), b, value = TRUE)`, but the `pattern` here is 'a' vector.  So, the values returned will be the values of 'b'

Comment: Thanks! It indeed solved my problem. cheers to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `paste` the elements of 'a' to a single expression pattern and use that in `grep`

```
grep(paste(a, collapse = "|"), b, value = TRUE)
```